# Git clone private github repository

Tags: git, github

I want to clone a private github repository to another device. In another question, the answer was to add username and password like this:

```
git clone 'https://username:password/github.com/username/repo/'
```

However, for me that resultet in the following error:

```
fatal. unable to access 'https://name:password/github.com/username/repo/': URL using bad/illegal format or missing URL
```

What am I doing wrong? I hope y'all can help me. Thank you!

**EDIT:**
I marked the question as duplicate, the suggested question solved my problem.

Comment: Note the `@` (not a `/`), there are also many different ways of providing credentials, in the linked question above. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I'll try that out. I looked through many different questions, but none of them helped me. Sorry for asking a duplicate question, I didn't see that one.

Comment: Jannik it's alright, I have it bookmarked for my colleagues :)

Answer (score 1):

Try git@github.com instead of https://

if still doesnt work follow below

The following steps should work

1. create an access token in git hub
2. git clone https://github.com/username/repo_name.git
3. Enter your username and use the access token as password

Comment: Thanks, the suggestions in the comments of my questions were already enough, simply replacing / with @ did it for me!